# Using your own (pre-built) html in Intel's XDK

Tags: javascript, android, emulation, intel, intel-xdk

I am very new to using Intel's XDK, I already have a web app that I need to convert to an android app. I have tested the html web app thoroughly and so far, it works perfectly in the browser. The problem is that when I imported it to the XDK, it doesn't seem to work on the emulators. I searched everywhere and no one else seems to have the same problem, so it must be I'm missing something. I know you have to insert an extra javascript (which I already did) but so far, it still doesn't work. Can anybody here point me to the right direction? Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width target-densitydpi=device-dpi initial-    scale=0.1 maximum-scale=0.5 user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>King</title>
    <style>
       html {
        height:100%;
       }
       body {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=1024" />

      <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style ="margin:auto;width:1024px;height:768px">
    <div id="king_hype_container"  style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1024px;height:768px;">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"  src="King.hyperesources/king_hype_generated_script.js?7046"></script>

    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm putting the intel xdk in the wrong place in javascript?

Comment: Can you post some code to help us see what you are trying to do? Can you be more specific with your question? Thanks

Comment: Sure, I'll post my code ASAP. I´m still very new to this. Thank you

Comment: try to remove the 'King.hyperesources/king_hype_generated_script.js?7046' script, the emulator work? if not just enter normal html layout without js, than it works?

Comment: It is indeed very strange... When I remove that line, it stops working (Doesn't show anything). Then, When I put it back, it shows the main page but the buttons don't work in the emulator (Haven´t yet tested on a real device), but it works perfectly when I use Live Preview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what @rscohn2 suggests (make that "king" script is local to your project, avoid loading it over the network if at all possible), but also take a look at [this "beefier" template](https://github.com/xmnboy/blank-xdk-cordova-project) which I've provided to people who are trying to turn a web app into a webview app. There are lots of comments and console.log messages to help you figure out what's going on, but, in essence:

- wait for the custom "app.Ready" event to kick off your app
- consider when you are loading your third-party and custom JS scripts (see the README)

Comment: Thank you for the blank template, I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't loading the king_hype_generated_script.js. You could see that by popping up the debugger in the emulator. You can do that by clicking on the bug icon in the top left of the screen and then looking at the messages in the console tab. you probably want to make king_hype_generate_script.js a static file and copy into your project, or use an absolute URL pointing back at your server. Copying it into your project will give you better ability to work offline.

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to be loading... But the buttons the javascript generates won't respond, at least in the emulator (Since every other project works fine in the emulator, i assume it is a problem with my code or something similar)